# Why is x not deleted in the below program?

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 1;
var output = (function() {
    delete x;
    return x;
 })();
console.log(output);
```

Is "delete" statement restricted only to objects?

Comment: `delete` may only be used to remove properties from objects. It cannot undeclare variables. You could hash it together by making `x` a property of `window` and then running `delete window.x`.

Comment: Read the docs on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Description States it pretty clear in the bullet points

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`delete` can only be used to remove object properties; it can't undeclare a variable (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Description) about it).

If you need to use this functionality, assign `x` to `window`:

```js
window.x = 1;

var output = (function() {
    delete window.x;
    return window.x;
})();

console.log(output);
```

**Note:** Generally, cluttering up the `window` object is bad practice and should be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are right. The `delete` operator removes a given property from an object. Please check this link for a full explanation: [MDN delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Answer (score 3):

Correct, `delete` is designed to be used on object properties. It has no effect on variables or functions.

Comment: Please upvote the answers already posted, instead of duplicating an answer.